# obj-c : remove the white background behind the Keyboard animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

i want to remove the white background behind the keyboard when it appear.

See the attached picture!

Thanks for help!

Comment: Go for it. You have our blessing.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. I've never seen such a background appear in any app, ever.

Comment: Initiate your question by explaining how you've got that white background instead of abruptly asking how to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say your code is not animating whatever it's doing to move stuff out from under the keyboard. Try putting that code in an animation block, or even removing it entirely. Use the `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` to match the keyboard's built-in animation.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you set an input accessory view. 
Make sure `[myTextView setInputAccessoryView:nil];`